# Como checar si la ultima celda de una tabla no esta oculta JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una funcion que me realiza una operacion matematica por cada fila que existe en una tabla, pero en esta tabla tengo una opcion para ocultar el input de la ultima celda, lo que deseo lograr es verificar si este input no esta oculto("hidden") y si si lo esta no realizar la operacion en esta fila, solo en las demas.

Esto es la funcion que llevo pero no me funciona lo de checar si es hidden el input:

```
function CalcularTotal () {
var subtotal = 0;
var total = 0;
var trLength = $("#tPedidos TBODY TR").length;
$("#tPedidos TBODY TR").each(function (index) {

    if (index === (trLength - 1)){
        return
    }

    f = $(this).find(':last')
    //console.log(f);
    if(f.visibility !== 'hidden') {

    var row = $(this);

        //Valor de Precio
        Precio = row.find("TD").eq(1).find('input').val();
        //console.log(Precio);
        //Valor de Cantidad
        CantidadPedido = row.find("TD").eq(2).find('input').val();
        //console.log(CantidadPedido);
        //subtotal de PRECIO * CAntidad y Total de cada fila
        subtotal = Precio * CantidadPedido;
        total += Number(subtotal);
        //console.log(total);
    }                
    });

    //Asignarle el valor al input
    $("#total").val(total);
    //console.log(total);          
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analizando tu código y la [documentación del método find](https://api.jquery.com/find/), parece que estás llamando una opción inexistente en tu `if`

```
if(f.visibility !== 'hidden') {
    ....
}
```

El resultado obtenido por `f.visibility` será `undefined`...

La forma correcta es llamando el método [css](https://api.jquery.com/css/) del objeto retornado por el `find`:

```
if(f.css("visibility") !== 'hidden') {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Ese era el problema muchas gracias!